# Script to copy a changing range of cells to another fixed set of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write a Script to copy a changing range of cells to another fixed set of cells but so far will only work with a fixed position range to copy from.

For example one time it may be Jobsheet!B2:F44 to Shop!A80, another time Jobsheet!L2:P44 to Shop!A80. There are many different ranges that may need to be copied but they always need to go to Shop!A80. The range shape of cells to be copied will always be 5 cols by 43 rows.

Can anyone help please?

Many Thanks

Comment: Could you share the sample sheet you are working on? that may give a better idea on what the script should do. Remember to always include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function copytosamedst() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Shop");
  const drgcolstart = 1;
  const drgrowstart = 80;
  let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Source Sheet/Range", "Enter Sheet Name/Range in A1Notation", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  let t = r.getResponseText().split('/');
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(t[0].trim());
  const svs = sh.getRange(t[1].trim()).getValues();
  dsh.getRange(drgrowstart, drgcolstart, dsh.getLastRow() - drgrowstart + 1, dsh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  dsh.getRange(drgrowstart,drgcolstart,svs.length,svs[0].length);
}
```

Let me know how it goes.  We will probably how to adjust

Comment: Hi @Cooper, Thanks for that. I was hoping to show which cells to use by clicking on the cell in the top left of the selection and then running the script. Eg. If it happened to be Jobsheet!L2:P44 then I would select L2 and run the script. Can you help with that please?

Comment: Please add all of that and perhaps some imagesto aid in our understand to your question

Comment: Does this help? It show what I want to happen not how to do it! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CXycwZfqtrxn0qtiKl2DzIIOsmKO1kLc/view?usp=sharing Thanks

Comment: I sort of understand what you are desiring but I need more information to carry it out.  We would probably have to meet and talk about it or you would have to provide us with more information.

Comment: -Cooper Ah Ok, Not to worry then. Many thanks for your efforts.